# Gridview header formatting

Tags: html, asp.net, gridview

I have a `GridView`. I am not adding any *style* in it but still it's giving me blue color header labels. How can I fix it.

My `GridView` is as follow.

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdViewApp" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="APPLICATION_ID,APPNAME,APPDESCRIPTION,REMARKS,VERSION,SCHEDULE_ID,AUTHENTICATION_TYPE"
                            BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="0px" Width="100%" BorderColor="Transparent" OnRowCommand="grdViewApp_RowCommand"
                            OnSorting="grdView_Sorting"  AllowSorting="true"  AllowPaging="true" PageSize="4"
                            OnPageIndexChanging="grdViewApp_PageIndexChanging" OnRowDataBound="grdViewApp_RowDataBound">
    <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="AltRow" />
    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
    <RowStyle CssClass="Row" />                                
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="left" ItemStyle-Width="5%">
            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="~/images/edit-icon.png" ID="ImgBtnEditApp" runat="server"
                                            Height="18" Width="18" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "RowIndex") %>'
                                            CommandName="EditApp" title="Edit Record"  />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="5%" />
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:BoundField DataField="APPLICATION_ID" HeaderText="ID" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="APPLICATION_ID">
            <ItemStyle Width="15%" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
        </asp:BoundField>

        <asp:BoundField DataField="AppName" HeaderText="Names" SortExpression="AppName">
            <ItemStyle Width="15%" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
        </asp:BoundField>

        <asp:BoundField DataField="AppDescription" HeaderText="Description" SortExpression="AppDescription">
            <ItemStyle Width="15%" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
        </asp:BoundField>

        <asp:BoundField DataField="Version" HeaderText="Version" SortExpression="Version">
            <ItemStyle Width="15%" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
        </asp:BoundField>
    </Columns>
 </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

The grid uses a table element as the header, plus since you have sorting enabled it also uses a header text with a link, so likely the style is coming from the header link.  You will have to use CSS to style the link to use another color.